# Tkinter button won't scroll with canvas

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

I have the following code, a simple window with a canvas and some buttons, one inside the canvas and the other bellow it.

the problem is that when I scroll up or down, the button "view" doesn't move at all, when it's suppose to

```
def initUI(self):
    self.content = Canvas()
    self.parent.title("window")
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("default")

    self.content.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    self.vbar=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
    self.vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.vbar.config(command=self.content.yview)
    self.content.config(yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)

    outButton = Button(self, text="I'm out", command=lambda: self.buttonOut())
    outButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    view = Button(self.content, text="View Profile", command=someting)
    view.place(x=235, y=160)

    self.pack()
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a solution, just have to add the button to a window and this window to the canvas

```
def initUI(self):
    self.content = Canvas()
    self.parent.title("window")
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("default")

    self.content.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    self.vbar=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
    self.vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.vbar.config(command=self.content.yview)
    self.content.config(yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)

    outButton = Button(self, text="I'm out", command=lambda: self.buttonOut())
    outButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
    view = Button(self.content, text="View Profile", command=someting)
-   view.place(x=235, y=160)
+   button_window = self.content.create_window(235, 160, window=view)

    self.pack()
```